# Wordpress Migrated from one domain to another new domain name

Tags: wordpress

I bought a new domain and I copied all files from the old domain web site to the new one.

Basically:

1) Copied all existing files, zip it and extract to new site folder.
2) Change settings in the wp-config (new connection settings) etc.

Everything is working great except one thing.

On my new site, I cannot see the top black " wordpress toolbar " anymore with my admin account (user id 1)
.
I can login, I can use the backend, everything.

IF I create a new user with admin privileges, the toolbar is working.
I disabled all plugins, switched to another theme, same.

Is there a setting i am missing somewhere that my user ID 1 is not displaying the toolbar?

Thanks

Comment: Judging by your question it doesn't seem like you have copied the database?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try switching to a different WordPress theme to see if the toolbar appears?

If it does, it could be a plugin causing some conflict in some way.

Hope this helps.